# Why have editing mamps php.ini no effect

Tags: php, macos, mamp, php-ini

I tried to raise the `upload_max_filesize` value in the php.ini (mamp 2.1.2 with the PHP version 5.4.10). The Server runs on port 80. I found several anwsers here but no one really applies.

When I use the `phpinfo ()` function to get the "Loaded Configuration File" I get the path: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini`, but the shown configuration form the `phpinfo ()` don't match with the configuration in my php.ini.

In my php.ini stands `upload_max_filesize = 100M` the phpinfo () tells me 2M.

After I edited the ini I restared the server and my machine.

So why can't I change the upload_max_filesize?

**Edite:**
After setting the Port to 8888 the config file is loaded correctly. Maybe there is a    conflict with the Apache-Server of the OS?!

Comment: I've tested it with PHP 5.4.4 on MAMP and it works without problems on the same path you stated. You might want to do `Stop Servers` then quit MAMP and check Activity Monitor if any php/mysql processes are still running. I had some issues in the past with MAMP running colliding versions that didn't really stop or hung after the MAMP application was shut down, causing these kind of erroneous problems.

Comment: Unfortunately this don't fix my problems. I restarted the hole computer and the values aren't changed.

Comment: This sounds silly, but it happens to a lot of experienced users. MAMP cashes pages. It might be that `phpinfo()` file you run still shows a cached version of the page. Also is the MASTER value the same as your LOCAL value? (the two separate columns in the `phpinfo()`). In Safari you can empty with `ALT+CMD+E`. If this doesn't work; try to upgrade to the latest MAMP and otherwise try the MAMP forums. This is a pretty odd issue.

Comment: I disabled/cleared the cache in my browser and in MAMP - the result is the samen, in addition both columns are showing the same (2M).

Answer (score 9):

This is because MAMP and MAMP PRO overwrites php.ini with a template file every time the services are started.  Therefore, to make your desired php.ini changes, you need to change the template.

In my instance using MAMP PRO on OS X, that template was found within:

```
/Applications/MAMP PRO/MAMP PRO.app/Contents/Resources/
```

In this folder, you will find several php.ini versions for each version of PHP that is available to you.  You will want to edit the .ini file for the PHP version you are running.  In my case, that was **php5.5.10.ini**.  After editing, restart your MAMP and your new settings should take effect.

Comment: thanks for this info... I found this solution perfect to my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Also you have to edit: `post_max_size` and `memory_limit`

> **post_max_size** integer
>       Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
>   **upload_max_filesize**. If memory limit is enabled by your configure
>   script, **memory_limit** also affects file uploading. Generally speaking,
>   memory_limit should be larger than post_max_size. When an integer is
>   used, the value is measured in bytes. Shorthand notation, as described
>   in this FAQ, may also be used. If the size of post data is greater
>   than **post_max_size**, the $_POST and $_FILES superglobals are empty.
>   This can be tracked in various ways, e.g. by passing the $_GET
>   variable to the script processing the data, i.e. , and then checking if
>   $_GET['processed'] is set.

php ini core [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Comment: I raised post_max_size to 100M but heres the same effect as with upload_max_filesize: The alterations have no effect (phpinfo shows 8M). The only thing I chaned with success was the value memory_limit (250M).

Comment: Which version are you using? MAMP or MAMP Pro?

Comment: I use the normal MAMP (not MAMP Pro)

Answer (score -2):

Try editing `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/conf/php.ini`
and restart the server.

Or try to set it programmatically

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '100M');
```

Comment: you can only do ini_set for uploads in .htaccess as php will reject the file before it hits the php script

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php   "Sets the value of the given configuration option. The configuration option will keep this new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending"

Comment: The file will be rejected __BEFORE__ the script executes, so it will never get set and used! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694114/php-file-size-limit